# Jenkins configure cross platform build system

Tags: jenkins, build, cross-platform

I'm trying to setup a simple build system with Jenkins for cross platform development.

We are building multiple pieces of software for Windows, MacOS and Ubuntu. The main flow of our build process now looks like:

- Pull from source ( Parameters: branch name )
- Make
- Build ( Parameters: Various, i.e. which software gets build )
- Post Processing ( Parameters: Various )
- ( MacOS ) code signing
- ( Centrally ) collecting all the results and sending them to a central location

Additionally, different versions of our software can only be build on specific versions of an OS ( mostly for older versions ), So we have multiple machines for the same platform.

How would I, on a specific trigger ( manually, script, periodically, commit ), start this procedure, where:

- **one** build is started for each of the platforms
- Depending on the parameters, the correct machine is selected.

Would this be a freestyle, pipeline, multiple pipelines, or other style of project.